# Forward a piped email,with attachments not working as the body text message is in an attachment

Tags: php

I am trying to forward a piped email,with attachments which is working but with two problems.

1. The forwarded email contains the mime headers in the message
2. The the orginal body text message has been attached as a html attachment and not in the message of the forwarded email

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
// Read in the email from STDIN
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email_content = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $email_content .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);

// Parse the email headers to get the original subject line
preg_match('/^Subject: (.+)$/m', $email_content, $matches);
$subject = $matches[1];

// Define the email address to forward the email to
$to_email = "example@example.com";

// Define the message for the forwarded email
$message = "This email was forwarded via PHP script.\n\nOriginal message:\n$email_content";

// Set the headers for the forwarded email
$headers = "From: example@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: example@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

// Get the email boundary string
preg_match('/boundary="(.+)"$/m', $email_content, $matches);
$boundary = $matches[1];

// Parse the email content to extract attachments
$attachments = array();
preg_match_all('/Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="(.+)"\s*Content-Type: (.+);\s*name=".+"\s*Content-Transfer-Encoding: (base64|quoted-printable|7bit|8bit|binary)\s*\r\n\r\n([^\r\n]*)\r\n--'.$boundary.'/sm', $email_content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $attachment = array(
        'name' => $match[1],
        'type' => $match[2],
        'data' => $match[4]
    );
    switch (strtolower($match[3])) {
        case 'base64':
            $attachment['data'] = base64_decode($attachment['data']);
            break;
        case 'quoted-printable':
            $attachment['data'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachment['data']);
            break;
    }
    $attachments[] = $attachment;
}

// Create the multipart message with attachments
$multipart_message = '';
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    $multipart_message .= "--$boundary\r\n";
    $multipart_message .= "Content-Type: {$attachment['type']}; name=\"{$attachment['name']}\"\r\n";
    $multipart_message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$attachment['name']}\"\r\n";
    $multipart_message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
    $multipart_message .= chunk_split(base64_encode($attachment['data']));
}
$multipart_message .= "--$boundary\r\n";
$multipart_message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$multipart_message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";
$multipart_message .= "$message\r\n";
$multipart_message .= "--$boundary--\r\n";

// Set the headers for the forwarded email with attachments
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";

// Forward the email with attachments
mail($to_email, $subject, $multipart_message, $headers, "-fexample@example.com");

// Stop extraneous and inappropriate email bounce email.
exit;

?>
```

`
I have tried changing the pregmatch for the boundaries but that didn't work

Comment: I keep reading how PHPMailer is a much better and more reliable way to handle email from PHP, certainly it seems that it would make this job a lot easier as I believe it handles attachments without you having to code it manually. I'm not sure if it would help in parsing the incoming email, if that's where the problem lies.

Comment: _"The original body text message has been attached as a html attachment and not in the message of the forwarded email"_ - the actual message part of the email that you are sending, appears to be `$message` - so did you expect the body content to automagically append itself to that on its own?

Comment: Apparently the body content ended up in your `$attachments` - so you should find the one with type `text/html` (or `text/plain`, not sure whether you are expecting a plain text or HTML email as the incoming one here), and append the content of that (perhaps stripped of HTML tags, if incoming was text/html) to your message ...